# people who expect others to conform to their will or ideas

Tags: word-request

I’m looking for a word to explain people who expect others to conform to their will or ideas.

Similar to bandwagon fallacy. But usually seen in petty mid level managers and narcissists.

Comment: Can you give an example of a typical situation where they show this behaviour? I've got a few ideas, but I'm not clear enough what you want, and I don't wan to give several different answers below

Comment: From the description of the tag that you chose: "Please demonstrate why you expect the word to exist in English. . . . Please use a bilingual dictionary and include the result of your research. Please include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with forceful or to impose. If you are forceful, you express your will strongly (perhaps physically, but this is not required).

"He imposed his own viewpoint about religion onto the others at the event"
"She has a very forceful personality, she always gets her way".

People often want to avoid imposing on others if they are being polite, it would be an imposition to expect someone to do something they don't want to do. However, some managers are very self centered and impose their ideas on others forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

A word doesn't explain people.
If you mean *describe* rather than *explain*, the word *bossy*, or a synonym such as can be found here might fit:

[Merriam-Webster synonyms of *bossy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bossy)
domineering, controlling... (or one of many others at the link)